# error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats. While using scipy.optimize.curve_fit

Tags: python, function, scipy, curve-fitting

I am trying to fit a function

```
def fun(x,a,b):
    return np.array((nsum(lambda i: (2*i-len(x)-1)*(1-(a*x+b))*x,
                         [0, len(x)]))/(nsum(lambda i: (1-(a*x+b))*x,[0, len(x)])*len(x)))
```

And this is the code for the fit

```
n=len(sim["avg"])
y= np.array([0.33]*n, dtype=float).reshape(n,)
x=np.array(sim["avg"], dtype=float).reshape(n,)
a,b =curve_fit(fun,x, y, method='trf')
```

n is the length of the data whil sim["avg"] is our x.
y in my case is constant, equals 0.33

This is the imports:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sympy import *
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit
from mpmath import nsum, exp, inf
```

This is sample data:

```
0        1250.0
1        1250.0
2        1250.0
3        1250.0
4        1250.0
         ...   
976    150000.0
977    150000.0
978    150000.0
979    150000.0
980    150000.0
```

This is the error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
TypeError: Cannot cast array data from dtype('O') to dtype('float64') according to the rule 'safe'

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-92-c1d0f29febb8> in <module>
      3 y= np.array([0.33]*n, dtype=float).reshape(n,)
      4 x=np.array(sim["avg"], dtype=float).reshape(n,)
----> 5 a,b =curve_fit(fun,x, y)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py in curve_fit(f, xdata, ydata, p0, sigma, absolute_sigma, check_finite, bounds, method, jac, **kwargs)
    782         # Remove full_output from kwargs, otherwise we're passing it in twice.
    783         return_full = kwargs.pop('full_output', False)
--> 784         res = leastsq(func, p0, Dfun=jac, full_output=1, **kwargs)
    785         popt, pcov, infodict, errmsg, ier = res
    786         ysize = len(infodict['fvec'])

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\minpack.py in leastsq(func, x0, args, Dfun, full_output, col_deriv, ftol, xtol, gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    420         if maxfev == 0:
    421             maxfev = 200*(n + 1)
--> 422         retval = _minpack._lmdif(func, x0, args, full_output, ftol, xtol,
    423                                  gtol, maxfev, epsfcn, factor, diag)
    424     else:

error: Result from function call is not a proper array of floats.
```

I was hoping that someone could either solve this error or could help with fitting this function which involves two summation (not sure if will work with Scipy).

Comment: What does `fun(x, 1, 2)` produce?

Comment: The function is actually a definition for gini coefficient while I am trying to find an optimal tax that makes G=0.33, I tried a linear first like this (1-(ax+b)). "1-" is for convenient calculation of the after tax income. The tax function is (ax+b).

Comment: What does the code actually produce?  I didn't ask about your intentions.  Is it an array with float dtype?  What shape?

Comment: `curve_fit` does `fun(x,a,b)-y` to test the fit.

Comment: So what should I do? In my function, return fun(x,a,b)-y instead fun(x,a,b). Then, when I do curve_fit, what ydata should I use?

Comment: I tried to run your `fun` to show what I want to see, but `nsum` is unknown.  The first part of the error message says that the result of this function call is an object dtype array that it cannot convert to float dtype.  It has to have a float array in order to compare it to your `y`.  Please go back and read the `curve_fit` documentation.  `curve_fit` will not work if the `fun` is not usable.

Comment: Sorry I forgot to include the imports          

" from mpmath import nsum, exp, inf"

Comment: You aren't making it easy to help you!   With `nsum` your function returns an object dtype array with `mpf` values.  Did you realize that?  Run the `fun(x,1,1)` as I asked you to????  Anyways, try making sure that `fun` returns a `float` dtype array, for example with a `return np.array(....).astype(float)`.